# Kafka 2.7.0: start service failing while making zookeeper connection

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have existing Kafka setup working as below -

```
Kafka - 2.4.1 (3 brokers)
Zookeeper - 3.6.2 (3 nodes)
```

Now I am upgrading Kafka version to 2.7.0, but when I downloaded the binary and trying to start service, it is failing while making connection with zookeeper, its not giving much error details/trace, only below logs.

```
INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
INFO Connecting to zookeeper on 10.1.13.74:2181,10.1.12.213:2181,10.1.11.190:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to 10.1.13.74:2181,10.1.12.213:2181,10.1.11.190:2181. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
INFO Client environment:host.name=ip-10-1-11-139.ec2.internal (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
INFO Client environment:java.version=11.0.9.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Red Hat, Inc. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-2.el7_9.x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
...
...
    [2021-04-29 11:37:52,874] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-04-29 11:37:52,874] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-04-29 11:37:52,874] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-04-29 11:37:52,874] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-04-29 11:37:52,874] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-04-29 11:37:52,874] INFO Client environment:os.version=3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-04-29 11:37:52,874] INFO Client environment:user.name=kafka (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-04-29 11:37:52,874] INFO Client environment:user.home=/home/kafka (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-04-29 11:37:52,874] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/srv/kafka/2.13-2.7.0/kafka_2.13-2.7.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
...
...
ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(java.lang.String, int, org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher, org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZKClientConfig)'
at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:111)
at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1881)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:441)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:466)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:233)
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
INFO App info kafka.server for 12 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

I tried to set logging mode to DEBUG but still not giving much information on why its not able to make connection with zookeeper, from logs its clear that it has initiated a zookeeper connection.

Another thing which I suspect is why it is giving zookeeper version 3.4.13 when my zookeeper server(which is on another machine) is version 3.6.2

```
INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
```

If I switch back to using kafka 2.4.1 & everything else as is it works fine, but not sure whats problem with kafka version 2.7.x/2.6.x

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Zookeeper client used by kafka is 3.4.13... If that class does actually exist in the new version, sounds like your classpath got modified in the upgrade process

Comment: Is it ok that Zookeeper client used by kafka is 3.4.13(zookeeper server is 3.6.2) ? I havent modified anything except using new version. If I switch back to kafka 2.4.1 keeping everything as is, it starts working.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure about Zookeeper client-server version compatibility. All I can say is that Kafka is generally only tested against the Zookeeper version it comes with